# Blurred Qt Quick Text

Tags: windows, qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

This is an example from Qt Quick examples inside Qt Creator, when I run the project all texts lost their quality and blurred, the attached picture describes clearly the problem.

Qt Version: 5.4.1

Platform: Windows 7

[image]

Comment: How can I solve that?

Comment: Try to set text renderType to **Text.NativeRendering** http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#renderType-prop

Comment: Looks like a graphic driver bug to me. Buttons automatically render natively to this cannot be the problem.

Comment: Any solution found? Same problem here

Comment: The controls are not blurred, just the text.

Comment: I also have this problem running QCAD 3.27 in Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an old bug that may be reproduced on some hardware when Qt uses system OpenGL capabilities ["[QTBUG-31983] Font rendering on Windows XP shows artifacts with QML Text element"](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31983)

Before Qt version 5.5 there are two types of Qt releases for Windows: ANGLE and OpenGL. They can be distinguished by the suffix "opengl" in the installer file name, for example:

```
qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.1.exe
qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.4.1.exe
```

See ["Qt 5 on Windows ANGLE and OpenGL"](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5_on_Windows_ANGLE_and_OpenGL) for the explanation.

The ANGLE build does not have such defect. Only OpenGL build is affected. OpenGL is poorly supported by default on many Windows installations. In some cases it can just crash during QML window initialization. The manual video driver installation was required. However, for some old hardware it is a problem to find such good video card driver that have enough support for OpenGL.

Possible solutions:

- Use ANGLE Qt build
- It is possible to subclass the standard QML `Text` control with default render type `Text.NativeRendering`:

> ```
> Text { renderType: Text.NativeRendering; }
> ```

ANGLE Qt build could be a good solution if Windows XP should not be supported.

If no intensive graphics usage is required the better solution is to use software OpenGL rendering. Before Qt 5.4 it is was possible to use MSYS Mesa library `opengl32.dll` (only some specific version should be used). If such library is placed in the executable folder of Qt application built with OpenGL Qt version, that library is automatically used for software rendering instead of default hardware rendering. Starting from Qt 5.4 such library is provided by Qt: `opengl32sw.dll` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html).

The software OpenGL emulation works perfectly on all types of hardware and it does not require any special video card driver.

Starting from Qt 5.4 there is the application attribute [`Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum):

> Forces the usage of a software based OpenGL implementation on
>   platforms that use dynamic loading of the OpenGL implementation. This
>   will typically be a patched build of [Mesa llvmpipe](http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html), providing OpenGL
>   2.1. The value may have no effect if no such OpenGL implementation is available. The default name of this library is `opengl32sw.dll` and can
>   be overridden by setting the environment variable `QT_OPENGL_DLL`. See
>   the platform-specific pages, for instance [Qt for Windows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html), for more
>   information. This value has been added in Qt 5.4.

Comment: Use QQuickWindow::setTextRenderType(QQuickWindow::NativeTextRendering).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my QT 5.4.2 MinGW project as well. Using Text.NativeRendering solved the blurry text in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This renders the font with native rendering. But not solves the problem with default Qt rendering.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 512
    height: 300

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World!"
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
    }
}
```